# R lwd below 1 actual value

Tags: r, graphics, par

On some plotting devices, settings of `lwd` below 1 get interpreted as `lwd=1` in R.

I would like to know how I can retrieve the actual value that my lwd setting will result in in my plotting device.

I am trying to code a plotting function which is supposed to do the same on all plotting devices (pdf, png, etc..) and for which I need to know how my lwd setting of e.g. 0.5 will appear.

I already tried e.g. plotting into my png device with setting `lwd` via `par` to an extremely low value and then retrieving `lwd` with `par("lwd")` after the plotting, but it would then return that exact value and not what my plotting command actually makes out of it. If the same is done with pdf, the problem does not occur, I guess since it is a vector-based format.

```
png("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test1.png")
par(lwd=0.0001)
plot(1,1)
print(par("lwd"))
dev.off()

png("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test2.png")
par(lwd=1)
plot(1,1)
print(par("lwd"))
dev.off()

pdf("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test1.pdf")
par(lwd=0.0001)
plot(1,1)
print(par("lwd"))
dev.off()

pdf("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test2.pdf")
par(lwd=1)
plot(1,1)
print(par("lwd"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you please show some example code for creating/generating a plot? Also note the help for `?png`: "Line widths are a multiple of 1/96 inch (interpreted at res ppi), with a minimum of one pixel (type = "windows") or 0.01 (type = "cairo")."

Comment: Thanks, that is useful! I am still wondering if I can get R to say:
"You are plotting into a png. Your lwd setting is 0.5. I interpret it as 1.0"

Comment: Or, analogously: "You are plotting into a pdf. Your lwd setting is 0.5. I interpret it as 0.5"